# How can i go back previous observed string

Tags: c#, string, back

Example

```
String context = string.Emty;

private void BtnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //First Click
  context = Abcd;
  TextboxText.Text = context; //Abcd 
  //Second Click
  TextboxText.Text = context; //new context = SADASD
  //Third Forth Fift click new string context
}

//Now how i can go back 5th string 4th string 3 2 1th string 
private void BtnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //Fift Forth Third Second First Observed string will show in the textbox
  // Reverse back previous string with sequence 
  TextBoxText.Text = context; // Will reverse/Go back in sequence 
}
```

How can i go back string

Even going forward forward string or and reverse back back . My english was not good enough to explain but if you are unable to understand what i was said please let me know

Comment: Read up about the Stack data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep references of the previous values. One approach is to keep a stack of strings where you push in the new value each time you hit `BtnForward_Click()` and pop (the most recent one) when you hit `BtnBack_Click()`. An example is given below:

```
    Stack context = new Stack();

    private void BtnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you would need to set the value of the Abcd based on your business logic
        context.Push(Abcd);
    }

    private void BtnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBoxText.Text = context.Peek(); // gets the most recently entered value of the stack that has not been removed (popped)
            context.Pop();                
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
        {
            // Nothing to go back to
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks it works going back string . but only one back.  suppose string[] context.push("Abcd") , second context.push("Efgh") , Third context.push("Ijkl") , 4th context.push("Mnop") .               result going back context.pop; context.peek = i get result 4th to Third context.peek => ("Ijkl") and next click third to 2nd not going it keep stack in 4th to 3rd . how it would be

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that you always get the previous string. I updated my answer to first get the `context.Peek()` and after that pop that element. Hope it helps.

Comment: Suppose in context.count = 4 .which mean i get 1 2 3 4 group of string in stack context list  . if i have push push("4") when i reverse back i get pop and peek 3 , if i push("3") i get pop and peek 2 .  is there a way => going back in sequence  string peek => reversing like this  group[4] next click group[3] next click group[2] next click group[1] ..    actually i mean equability navigation back _request

Comment: Hello It works `context.Pop(); TextBoxText.Text = context.Peek(); //Again
            context.Pop(); ` Thanks again problem fixed

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, it is advisable to upvote and/or accept it as answer.

Comment: ohh i forget that , sorry , done : thanks